# c# : setting an image to pictureBox from List<Bitmap> in another class gives following error: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, list, bitmap, picturebox

I am taking bitmap images from camera and store them in a List< Bitmap>.

Within the same class I can set pictureBox images directly from the list like:

```
pictureBox1.Image = imagesToReturn[0];
```

where imagesToReturn is a List< Bitmap>.

The problem occurs when I call this method from a different class. ('invalid parameter' error is thrown).

- First I return the list from the first object,
- then copy it in the second object,
- and then destruct the first object.

When I check the returned list I see they are returned correctly (Check the image below; [2] is intentionally null).

Do you guys have any idea what might be the problem or how can I solve this?
Thanks for your valuable time and help.

[image: QuickWath of the returned list]

*(edit: long story short, The list you see on the picture above cannot be loaded to pictureboxes because of the 'invalid parameter' error)*

Here are some of the codes:
These are in the first class and work perfectly:

```
/*These are in the first class and works perfectly.*/
 public static List<Bitmap> ImagesToReturn = new List<Bitmap>();
 public static void updateThumbnails(Bitmap img, int* pictureBoxIndex)
    {
        switch (*pictureBoxIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                ImagesToReturn[0] = img;
                pictureBox2.Image = ImagesToReturn[0];//so that I know they are stored correctly.
                pictureBox2.Refresh();
                break;
            case 2:
                ImagesToReturn[1] = img;
                pictureBox3.Image = ImagesToReturn[1];
                pictureBox3.Refresh();
                break;
            case 3:
                ImagesToReturn[2] = img;
                pictureBox4.Image = ImagesToReturn[2];
                pictureBox4.Refresh();
                break;
            case 4:
                ImagesToReturn[3] = img;
                pictureBox5.Image = ImagesToReturn[3];
                pictureBox5.Refresh();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        *pictureBoxIndex = 0;

        img.Dispose();
    }

public List<Bitmap> returnCapturedImageList()
    {
        return ImagesToReturn;
    }


//Done button. Terminates the processes.
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

    {
        keepRunning = false; // in order to stop straming
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }
```

And these are at the second class:

```
public static List<Bitmap> returnedImages = new List<Bitmap>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication6.Form2 cameraModule = new WindowsFormsApplication6.Form2();            

        var result = cameraModule.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             returnedImages = cameraModule.returnCapturedImageList()

            pictureBox1.Image = returnedImages[0]; //ERROR is thrown here!
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

            cameraModule.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            cameraModule.Close();

        }
        returnedImages.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: is `pictureBox1.Image = storedImages[0];` right ? i think it should be `pictureBox1.Image = returnedImages[0];`

Comment: if possible put your code so we can understand and can help you more

Comment: i know just kidding, can you please put code so we can understand more

Comment: Aye aye captain! give me 5 minutes.. :)

Comment: try with `pictureBox1.Image = returnedImages[0].value;`

Comment: No captain, still exists. I've also tried returnedImages.ElementAt(0); but the result is the same.

Comment: _pictureBox3.Image = ImagesToReturn[1];_ You know that this does not make a copy of the image, right? Also: Is there __any__ reason to use pointers?

Comment: Yes buddy. this is where I make a copy: "returnedImages = cameraModule.returnCapturedImageList() ". And yes I had to use pointers since we cannot pass reference in recursive functions, although it is irrelevant with the problem. Thanks for your time. If anything comes to your mind I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I don't see anything recursive in your function.  Also, you have a static method that is referencing PictureBox instances, presumably on a form.  That won't work.

Comment: Well, it is normal because the codes above are just some parts of the project. Just enough for programmers to understand where the problem might be... Also, the static function is not made up, and that part works perfectly. The actual problem is with the second part of the codes. Thanks for your time. I appreciate that.

Comment: img.Dispose()? Are you sure about this? aren't you trying to access disposed images?

Comment: Actually no.  First I add the 'img' to 'ImagesToReturn', and then dispose the 'img' . Since it will be stored in the list, no need to keep it anymore.

Comment: The img in the list is not a copy.

Comment: user6144226, and LarsTech. You were right. You made me understand what the problem was. Thank you guys. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The issue is solved thanks to the   [user6144226](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144226/user6144226) and [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech). They actually pointed out the mistake.*

```
 ImagesToReturn[0] = img; /*not copying or cloning*/
 ImagesToReturn[1] = img;
 ImagesToReturn[2] = img;
 ImagesToReturn[3] = img;
```

The statements above were not copying image to the list. It was pointing to the 'img'. In other words, when I disposed the 'img' with following command:

```
 img.Dispose();
```

the "ImagesToReturn[n]" was pointing to the memory that has already been disposed.

The proper way to do it was as follows:

```
ImagesToReturn[0] = new Bitmap(img); /*copying*/
ImagesToReturn[1] = new Bitmap(img);
ImagesToReturn[2] = new Bitmap(img);
```

And that solved the issue.